# Left join 3 times same table on 3 conditions multiples results

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Here is the thing, I have table like this

First one

```
ID1 ID2 ID3
```

Second

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 month, value
```

What I need is to get values for three months for each combination of these 3 IDs, and I went this way:

```
SELECT a.ID1, a.ID2, a.ID3, b.value, c.value, d.value
FROM Table1 a

LEFT JOIN Table2 b
ON a.ID1 = b.ID1
AND a.ID2 = b.ID2
AND a.ID3 = b.ID3
WHERE month=2


LEFT JOIN Table2 c
ON a.ID1 = c.ID1
AND a.ID2 = c.ID2
AND a.ID3 = c.ID3
WHERE month=3


LEFT JOIN Table2 d
ON a.ID1 = d.ID1
AND a.ID2 = d.ID2
AND a.ID3 = d.ID3
WHERE month=4
```

And I got values multiplied.

Any idea why this is case, or any suggestions for other approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me like you don't need `table1` at all to satisfy this query, since all of the information in the output is also in `table2`.

Comment: Table1 contains all necessary rows that should have results calculated, even if there is no values in table 2.

Comment: And I've updated it again based on more information I've managed to pull from you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the next 3 months (next month and the two following months) based on today's date, you can do this (you can also set @base to any specific date to the get the three following months):

```
DECLARE @base DATETIME = GETDATE();

;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT a.ID1, a.ID2, a.ID3, 
      m = DATEADD(MONTH, b.[Month]-1, RTRIM(b.[Year])+'0101'), b.value
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS a INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS b 
    ON a.ID1 = b.ID1 AND a.ID2 = b.ID2 AND a.ID3 = b.ID3
), y AS
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, m, md = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @base, m), value
    FROM x
    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, @base, m) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
)
SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, 
    BValue = SUM(CASE WHEN md = 1 THEN value END),
    CValue = SUM(CASE WHEN md = 2 THEN value END),
    DValue = SUM(CASE WHEN md = 3 THEN value END)
FROM y 
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, ID3;
```

Comment: I have year too, but I didn't mention it, to not complicate question. And I have to go three months upfront. I have variables @m and @y, and I did it like this: first where "month = @m+1", second: m+2, and so on. I also wrote cases when month passes 12:

Example for third one: 
d.month = 
(
CASE
WHEN @m >= 10
THEN @m - 9
ELSE @m + 3
END
)
AND d.year = 
(
CASE
WHEN @m >= 10
THEN  @y + 1
ELSE  @y
END
)

Comment: You should include all relevant information in the question. Don't leave things out because you think they're too complex.

Comment: Sorry, but nevertheless, thank you for idea, I'll try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put there `WHERE month=x` right in the `inner join`, if it were an `outer join` it wouldn't work the same.

Comment: I think that isn't the problem, I tried putting this in three temp tables, where I inserted rows with that "where", and also tried joining on "month=x", same problem in both cases.